# HP Probook 450 G3 - screen brightness hotkeys not recognized

Tags: shortcut-keys, brightness, hp

I've purchased this laptop: T6P76EA#ABF. The hotkeys to increase or decrease screen brightness seems to not being mapped, whatever options I can put on grub command line (i.e. acpi_backlight=video/vendor/native/none). In fact acpi_event doesn't see anything, and journalctl says to "setkeycode" to recognize the keys. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Well I used setkeycodes in rc.local:

```
setkeycodes e012 122
setkeycodes e017 124
```

then xev told me the keys number and so is my .xmodmaprc:

```
keycode 130 = XF86MonBrightnessDown
keycode 132 = XF86MonBrightnessUp
```

and now it work 8-)